# setup security in mongodb on windows

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb setup on two nodes and one arbiter. Till now we didn't have security configured. I want make environment secure. Need help in setting up users. Also want to know what options should be used in the config file.

Comment: It would be only proper that you first read documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/ and check what kind of authentication service you want to integrate with mongodb. Quick steps to do a user setup https://medium.com/@matteocontrini/how-to-setup-auth-in-mongodb-3-0-properly-86b60aeef7e8. All this by just a quick google

Comment: Thanks for replying. From the documentation I found the command to add a user. After adding user I put authorization: "enabled" in the config file and restarted mongodb service. After restarting service when I connect using the added user, it says login failed. Also anonymous login is still working even though I put authorization: "enabled".

Comment: then you did something wrong in the steps. I too had followed tutorial and documentation and it had worked just fine for simple auth.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/. You know you should post the steps you took and error you are getting. They way you are asking question here at stackoverflow is not the accepted way to ask question